# Can't find the "free space" in the partition table while installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to install ubuntu with pre-installed Win 8.1, I shrinked the C parition and I have the unallocated parition in disk management .But when I am at the parition table step in installing ubuntu , I can't find the "free space" in the parition.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your dynamic partition to one logical partition. Then do this steps.

1. Download and Install [EASEUS Partition Master Professional Edition](http://easeus-partition-master-professional.en.softonic.com)
   (my favorite app ;) )
2. Run EASEUS Partition Master then click `Go to main screen` option.
3. Here, select the partition which you want to install Ubuntu. In your case select 31.25GB unallocated partition and right-click on it and select `Create Partition`. Under the `Create as` drop-down, select `Logical` and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
4. Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button at the top of EASEUS window (under view menu) then click <kbd>Yes</kbd>. This operation needs to restart your computer to completing
5. Finish

If you continue the Ubuntu installation from (USB/CD) you will see the unallocated space.

Comment: I have this [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/MeOnDUx.png)

Comment: @MedAL Yes click on convert to basic disk and then select your desired partition and select convert to logical then follow to continue installation

Comment: after the operation done it give me this http://i.imgur.com/dfGR5t7.png

Comment: @MedAL Click NO and goto their  proprieties  and run check disk for each partition and then try to convert.

Comment: Thanks , I change the disk to basic and the free space appeared

Comment: Is there any free alternative to EaseUS tool?

Comment: I have an unallocated space but still neither the "free space" nor the "install ubuntu alongside"  option is showing

Comment: Not everyone can purchase the professional softwares.

Comment: @SAndrew hey, wait, it has free trial and that part is always available even after free trial period finished, I didn't purchase it, and it's one time job to change to logical