# Not able to see unallocated free space while installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am Installing `ubuntu 16.04` alongside `windows 10`. I have two unallocated space in my hard disk as below:

[image]

But when installing the `ubuntu` and selecting `something else` option, I get below:

[image]

I am not able to understand why its not showing unallocated free space while installing the ubuntu. Also, how can I merge these two unallocated space into one?

Thanks

Comment: Two words: Dynamic Disks. A Microsoft proprietary technology you activated that is not supported in Linux.

Comment: Is there anyway to disable it.?

Comment: AFAIK Microsoft says no, reformat, reinstall, that's it. But there are third-party tools that claim they can convert the partitions back to basic. That's a Windows question though. Google it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/65939/931000 **Carefully** read all the answers and comments.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia What about this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538292/cant-find-the-free-space-in-the-partition-table-while-installing-ubuntu) is it okay to convert the partition ?

Comment: That's one of the tools I've mentioned. Don't know, never used it. If you have backups it's worth trying, I guess.

Comment: I am not able to download a free version of EASEUS software. I am also not able to download any other free software which can convert. Do you have any idea of any free software.?

Comment: Sorry, no. And again, that part is all Windows and off-topic here.